# Update table from another sub-query table - "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, join, plsql, sql-update

I am trying to figure out how to update a table from another table which is a result of a query in PL/SQL.

This is what I try to do:

```
update c
set c.customerType = n.newType
from customers c
join 
    (select 
         c.customerNumber, c.customerType, 
         case when c.customerType = 'business' and count(s.subCode) = 1 
                 then 'small business' 
                 else null  
         end as NewType
     from customers c
     join subscribers s on c.customerNumber = s.customerNumber
     group by c.customerNumber, c.customerType) n on c.customerNumber = n.customerNumber;
```

Note, that table customers look like this:

```
customerNumber   customerType
------------------------------
1                business
4                business
2                private
3                private
```

table n (sub-query) gives the following result:

```
customerNumber   customerType   newType
1                business       null
4                business       small business
3                private        null
2                private        null
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S eventually I would like to update customerType with newType only where it is not null..

Thanks

Comment: Oracle doesn't support the `from` clause in an `update`, so your question is quite unclear.

Comment: so how am I to this in oracle? i.e. how do I update one table from another table which is a result of a sub-query? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a correlated subquery.  In your case, though, I think all the work can be done in the outer `where` clause:

```
update customers c
    set c.customerType = 'small business'
    where c.customerType = 'business' and
          (select count(s.subcode)
           from subscribers s
           where s.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
          ) = 1;
```

This updates "business" customers to "small business", if the customer has exactly one `subcode` in the `subscribers` table.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured there should be an easier way of doing it, but this is the first time I am trying to understand the update. I'd appreciate if you can explain why my way doesn't work, i.e. what do you mean by correlated subquery. Thanks

Comment: @Hana . . . Your method doesn't work because the syntax for your database doesn't support `from` with an `update`.  A correlated subquery is the subquery in the `where` clause.  The inner `where` relates the tables in the inner `from` clause to tables in the outer `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

```
UPDATE customers
SET customerType = ( SELECT N.newType 
                        FROM
                        (
                            SELECT c.customerNumber, c.customerType, CASE WHEN c.customerType = 'business' AND count(s.subCode) = 1 THEN 'small business' ELSE NULL END AS NewType
                            FROM customers c1 JOIN subscribers s ON c1.customerNumber = s.customerNumber
                            GROUP BY c1.customerNumber, c.customerType
                        ) N
                    );
```

Comment: thanks, I tried to run your code, but I get an error on the last kine (AS N) - missing right parenthesis, but there is no missing parenthesis..

Answer (score 0):

```
you to write plsql like below
=============================
   declare
     cursor c1 is
        select c.customerNumber, c.customerType, 
             case when c.customerType = 'business' and count(s.subCode) = 1 then 'small 
              business'
             else null end as NewType
        from customers c,subscribers s
        where c.customerNumber = s.customerNumber
        group by c.customerNumber, c.customerType;
begin
for cur in c1 loop
     update customers set customer_type = cur.NewType
     where customerNumber = cur.customerNumber;
     commit;
end loop;
end;
```